# Hyper-V manager on a DC (Windows 2012)

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller

I know it's not possible to run the Hyper-V role on a domain controller, but is it possible to run the Hyper-V manager on a dc to manage other hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to run the Hyper-V role on a Domain Controller, it's just not recommended.

Yes, you can run the Hyper-V management tools on a DC to manage a remote machine, but I hesitate to say that it's recommended.  Ideally, your DC *should* just be a DC, not a management platform, but I suppose sometimes that can't be helped.

If you have any Windows 8 machines, you can install and use the Hyper-V management tools there to manage Hyper-V on remove Server 2012 or Windows 8 machines, which is definitely the recommended way to do it.